# Can't add skin control

Tags: .net, vb.net, skin

I can't get any Skin-Control to work; when I add it, it keeps falling down to the box under the form design like this (regular control still work):

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Obviously, something is broken. It's easy to fix.